# Extract characters in double quotes from a string in vb.net

Tags: .net

In `vb.net`, how would I extract the path of the following string, so that I end up with: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\HDH\hds_remove.vbs`

```
CSCRIPT //NOLOGO "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\HDH\hds_remove.vbs"
```

Comment: have you tried `IndexOf` and `SubString`?

Comment: There are about 50 different ways to do this. The best will depend on the context: is it just this one string, or other there other like it? If there are others, how can they vary?

Answer (score 0):

First call [IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof-vbnet) to get the indices of the quotes.

Then call [SubString](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet) to extract the path between the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Simply

```
   Dim tex = "CSCRIPT //NOLOGO \"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\HDH\hds_remove.vbs\""
   Dim substring As String = text.Substring(18, str.Length()-2)
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for the answer.  Well, the path needs to stay the same, I just want to know how to separate C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\HDH\hds_remove.vbs from everything else.  Basically something like split the string at the first " and remove the last ".